handleDeeplink function not called on Singular-SDK on iOS
I'm in the process of implementing the following documentation to handle deep links in my iOS app, but it seems that it's not being called correctly. What could be wrong with my code?
Here's the code I'm using:

Links will opened my app but callback is not working

You can test your universal link url in following link, https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/#resultsbox
